# Amazon AWS: DynamoDB requirements

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Objective: Using iPhone app, I would like the users store objects in DynamoDB and have Fine-Grained Access Control for the objects using IAM with TVM.

The objects will contain only Strings, no images/file storage --  I'm thinking I won't need an S3?

Question:  Since there is no server-side application, do I still need an EC2 Instance?  What all suite of AWS services will I have to subscribe to in order to accomplish my objective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either DynamoDB (or S3), and neither of them would require an EC2 instance - there is no dependency.

If it was me, I'd first see if I could get what I wanted down in S3(because you mentioned it as a possibility), and then go to DynamoDB if I couldn't (i.e. I wanted to be able to run agregation queries across my data set). S3 will be cheaper and depending on what your are doing, may even be faster and would allow you to globally distribute the stored data thru CloudFront easily, which if you have a globally diverse user base may be beneficial.

Comment: Do you have any experience with IAM and TVM?  Here is another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22078117/amazon-aws-iam-with-tvm  Thanks.