# Amazon AWS: IAM with TVM

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I'm working on an iOS App.  I would like to setup user authentication.  i.e.  User provides a username and password, and gets authenticated with TVM. The user access to AWS resources is regulated based on their credentials.

1. How do I set this up?  Is IAM with TVM enough to setup a Username/Password authentication?
2. Do I need a third party authentication provider like Singly or StormPath?
3. I would like the user to get authenticated and receive a "profile" which may include firstName, lastName, etc.  What's the best way to set this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The AWS site does contain [step-by-step instructions](http://aws.amazon.com/code/7351543942956566) for setting up an example identity TVM. We have also created a [CloudFormation template](https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx371Y7CA0QJ95X/Simplifying-Token-Vending-Machine-Deployment-with-AWS-CloudFormation) for simplifying the deployment.  It is important to note that this is just an example and can and should be customized to meet your needs.
2. The sample TVM does not require an external auth, but you can certainly add that if you feel it is necessary for your use case.
3. You can update the example TVM to store this, the source code is [available on GitHub](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-tvm-identity).

You might also consider using [web identity federation](https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx3UKF4SV4V0LV3/Announcing-Web-Identity-Federation) and leveraging Facebook, Google, or Amazon as your identity provider. Depending on your use case, this may provide all the identity information you need.

Comment: Thank you Bob!  I'm learning a lot from your re-invent videos on Youtube!  

1.  Can we combine TVM and WIF?  Meaning, on the Mobile apps we provide the user an option to either login with Facebook, Google, or Amazon, and/or create a new profile with TVM?  

2.  Where does TVM store the user/name profile etc. information?  Do I have to maintain that with DynamoDB?

3.  IAM has a limit of 5000 Users.  Does TVM also have a limit?

Comment: @user1107173 Glad you are finding the videos useful! The example TVM available on the website uses SimpleDB, but the combo TVM and geo server we used for [the mobile photo share App](https://github.com/awslabs/reinvent2013-mobile-photo-share) stores the info in DynamoDB. You would have to manage this DB yourself, as well as the TVM backend, though deploying to Beanstalk does make this easier. You can certainly combine the TVM and web identity federation, either just in the application or in the TVM itself, but doing the later would require updating the TVM.

Comment: Got it working with the template -- thank you! I'm able to see the users via the SimpleDB Chrome Extension. Any suggestions on how to implement password recovery for the Users? –

Comment: Your docs state that we can modify the TVM for password recovery.  What do we have to send to the server to email the password?  I did modify the TVM to also store an email address as a field (attribute).  Is there anything special I need to know?  Thanks.

Comment: Let me rephrase the question:  I'm also asking the user to provide an email address that I'm storing as a field (attribute).  How do I send a temporary password/code to their email that'll allow the user to create a new password?  Thanks!

Comment: @user1107173 Unfortunately I don't have any specific recommendations. If you have the user's e-mail there are any number of solutions you can use to send e-mail, including [Amazon SES](http://aws.amazon.com/ses/). You'll need to implement a new request handler in the TVM to allow for the password to be reset and will probably want to implement logic to make the recovery time bound (tokens expire after X hours for instance).